# Print lines after raising exception

Tags: python, dictionary, error-handling, raise

Is there a way to print out the contents of a dictionary after raising an exception?

Assuming that the dictionary is this,

```
d = {"orange":[1,2], "yellow":[5], "red":[2,6,7]}
```

I would like it to look something like this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-719ba08e2a6c> in <module>
----> 1 raise TypeError("This is a TypeError. Printing out contents of dictionary...")

TypeError: This is a TypeError.
orange
1
2

yellow
5

red
2
6
7
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You use `try/except` to perform actions when an exception is raised. You can print the dictionary in the `except` block.

Comment: Could you please provide what you have attempted for this question, so that we can guide you to the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Append the dictionary to the exception message.

```
raise TypeError("This is a TypeError. Printing out contents of dictionary...\n" + str(d))
```

Answer (score 0):

The format is not right, but this does the trick.

```
d = {"orange":[1,2], "yellow":[5], "red":[2,6,7]}

try:
    d["melon"]
except:
    raise Exception(f"{str(d)}")
```

or you can do:

```
try:
    d["melon"]
except:
    for k in d.keys():
        print(k, d[k])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
try:
    # code here
except Exception as e:
    # Try and replace `Exception` with the error you're getting
    print(f"Error = {e}")
    for name, val in zip(d.keys(), d.values()):
        print(name)
        for i in val:
            print(i)
```

Just be mindful that with `except Exception:`, the `try` loop will except **any** error